# Can Launchy's Weby plugin work with Opera?

Tags: opera, productivity

I want to use Opera as my default web browser because I really want to use the keyboard navigation feature. Using the keyboard (more) helps quell the tendinitis in my wrists.

I use Launchy to launch programs, search, etc.

**Problem:**

- Launchy's Weby works with IE, Firefox, Chrome, but it doesn't work with Opera
- "Doesn't work" = it doesn't follow (execute) the link generated by Weby

**Suspicion:**

- IE, Firefox, Chrome seem to adhere to the same convention for accessing the address bar (i.e. hit F6 in all and it selects the address bar), and Opera doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Opera, by the way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, Opera works with Weby from Launchy.

Maybe it's a matter of versions, but typically, if I try with "lets search something", it opens "http://www.google.com/search?source=launchy&q=lets%20search%20something" in Opera, in a new tab.

I'm using Opera 10.0 beta 3, and Launchy 2.1.2

---

Note that if you use a 10.0 beta like me, opening a link (execute) with Opera being initially closed, will probably not work if you use "save previous session". For me, it opens Opera with the restored session, but not with the new link. But this is a known issue from the beta. It works if you open a link, with Opera already opened.

---

This opening link from a closed Opera worked with the 9.x versions, so I guess it will work again, it's only a temporary bug during beta. In general, this problem happens too if you try to click a link in some other software, when it will require Opera to open, it won't work on first try.

For now, what you can do is to write in Launchy your Weby request ; it will open Opera, without your wanted link ; call launchy again and press enter directly, to send again the same request ; this time it will work.

Keep in mind that this is a temporary issue from Opera beta, and will most likely be fixed in the final version.

---

If the problem is in Opera 9.64 too, then maybe I'm wrong, and I remember badly. Maybe I was not saving sessions then, I'm not sure. Anyway, I'll submit it to Opera, restoring session or not, it should open the link.

---

**Update on the problem**

The issue with Opera, which was not opening links from external, on launch, has been solved in the Release Candidate version. You can find it here : http://www.opera.com/browser/next/ (or use the [direct link to installer](http://snapshot.opera.com/windows/Opera_1000_1733_in.exe)).

I checked with Launchy and its Weby plugin, it works now correctly, even if Opera is closed.

Comment: Thanks! You're right it does work with Opera open. Is there any way to get it to work with Opera initially closed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be a pest, but I was using 10.0 beta 3 and I've just gone back to 9.64, and it doesn't support Weby links from a closed state either. Is there a specific startup setting I have to use?